# Sset date and format date error

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, format

I have the following code:

```
               var duration = $('#duration').val();
               var now = new Date();
               var expire = new Date();
               expire.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + duration);


               alert("expire: " + expire + "now: " + now);
               var expireString = expire.format("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
               alert(expireString);
```

duration is 60 seconds. 
The result is:

1. the expire date is not 60 seconds later, but quite random every time
2. second alert is not prompt out (format error? )

[image]

Comment: Can you please share screen shot what error is coming out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no format method on the Date object in javascript, that's why you don't get the second alert. Have a look at [10 ways to format time and date using JavaScript](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3) for how to achieve what you want

Comment: 404 - Error! - Page not found

Answer (score 0):

```
           var duration = $('#duration').val();
           var now = new Date();
           var expire = new Date();
           expire.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + duration);
           alert("expire: " + expire + "now: " + now);
           var expireString = expire.format("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
           alert(expireString);
```

The first block of code runs as it is fine.

```
           var duration = $('#duration').val();
           var now = new Date();
           var expire = new Date();
           expire.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + duration);
           alert("expire: " + expire + "now: " + now);
```

The other set of block has errors as the format function is not built in that why second alert is not showing and giving error expire.format is not a function.

i you want to format expire string to a certain level for supporting time string you mentioned . you  must use it like this.

```
var timestamp = 1391164672; 
var pubDate = new Date(timestamp * 1000); //expects milliseconds var pubDate = new   Date(); pubDate.setTime(timestamp * 1000); 
 var weekday=new Array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");
 var monthname=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"); 
 var formattedDate = weekday[pubDate.getDay()] + ' ' + monthname[pubDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + pubDate.getDate() + ', ' + pubDate.getFullYear() + ' '+ pubDate.toLocaleTimeString();
```

Comment: is the first fine on your computer? on mine, the date time is wrong

Comment: if i can assign 60 to the duration like this: var duration = 60; then its alert check in your console that the $('#duration').val(); is give you the value from control or try by $('#duration').text() or $('#duration').html() to take value and use it.